# strange memory leak with python + paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I have an (apparent) memory leak in a python script that I can't quite explain (the resident memory just keeps growing).  It started off with about 6MB resident, I left it running overnight and it had gotten to over 200MB  (I did that to rule out a sawtooth memory usage pattern due to gc).  I've condensed it down to this script:

```
import sys
import time
import paramiko

def update():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(hostname='localhost')
    finally:
        ssh.close()

def main():
    while(True):
        update()
        time.sleep(0.001)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

I thought the problem might be that I keep instantiating a new SSHClient and they somehow weren't getting thrown out, but this version leaks memory even faster!

```
import sys
import time
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
def update():
    global ssh
    try:
        ssh.connect(hostname='localhost')
    finally:
        ssh.close()

def main():
    while(True):
        update()
        time.sleep(0.001)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

If anyone could shed some light on this, or if I'm just being dumb and someone can point out why I'd be most appreciative.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I managed to reproduce. When investigating, i found that most probably, the leak is connected to libssl, because there is growing allocation

Before:

```
35aaa53000-35aaa5b000 rw-p 00053000 00:11 3360939                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0j
...
7f4530000000-7f453013b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:               1260 kB
Rss:                1012 kB
Pss:                1012 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:      1012 kB
Referenced:         1012 kB
Anonymous:          1012 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
7f453013b000-7f4534000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:              64276 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
```

After some time:

```
35aaa53000-35aaa5b000 rw-p 00053000 00:11 3360939                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0j
...
7f4530000000-7f4530250000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:               2368 kB
Rss:                2120 kB
Pss:                2120 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:      2120 kB
Referenced:         2120 kB
Anonymous:          2120 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
7f4530250000-7f4534000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:              63168 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
```

Seems like bug in libssl or paramiko itself, because the gc.garbage is empty and len(gc.get_objects()) is constant, meaning there are no unbreakable cycles and no new python objects (using your first version).

BTW, you can run gc.collect() each iteration to avoid the sawtooth.

Answer (score 1):

Seems at least one other user has run into this recently on Paramiko's IRC; I created a ticket to track it here: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/182 - sadly I've no wisdom to share myself as this level of problem is not one I have experience troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

These days I meet the same issue.I think this is the bug of the lib.
In the same time your usage is not correct.
The key issue is you did't define the key file.According to the AutoAddPolicy source code:

```
 def missing_host_key(self, client, hostname, key):
        client._host_keys.add(hostname, key.get_name(), key)
        if client._host_keys_filename is not None:
```

You can change the policy handler to WarningPolicy or define a empty handle by yourself.
such as:

```
class DoNothingPolicy ():
    def missing_host_key(self, client, hostname, key):
        pass
```